# Adding custom Ansible module from a python library?

Tags: python, ansible, setuptools

Is it possible to add custom modules (for local usage) to Ansible, simply by installing a package with pip ?

The reason for this is to have an easy way to distribute and deploy our Ansible code.

Comment: Seems to be perfectly possible: https://pypi.org/search/?q=+ansible+module, https://pypi.org/search/?q=+ansible+modules

Comment: This module does what you want. https://github.com/TerryHowe/ansible-modules-hashivault

Comment: Why didn't I think about checking PyPi for examples myself ? :-) I'll have a look right away.

Comment: The Hashicorp Vault example works beautifully. I presume the secret lies in the directory structure. Thx !

Comment: All of sudden I'm getting the error. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ansible.module_utils.basic'. No clue where this comes from. It used to work.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible indeed. As suggested earlier, there are a number of examples in the field. The point is to put the code into a top level package named 'ansible/modules/...' and the supporting code in 'ansible/module_utils'.